# pandas dataframe 2 dim index slice

Tags: numpy, pandas, slice

I am having trouble with a 2 dim index slice.

I have the following dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([(11,91),(12,92),(13,93),(14,94),(15,95)],columns =list('AB'))

   A   B
0  11  91
1  12  92
2  13  93
3  14  94
4  15  95
```

Then I will have a "index array"

```
df_index = pd.DataFrame([(4,4),(4,0),(0,3),(2,2),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(0,4)],columns =list('xy'))
   x  y
0  4  4
1  4  0
2  0  3
3  2  2
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  1
7  0  4
```

I want to use the df_index on df to return. You see how the values are selected on index for each column

```
   A_x  B_y
0  15  95
1  15  91
2  11  94
3  13  93
4  12  92
5  12  92
6  12  92
7  11  95
```

I can do this by creating a loop and doing an index on each column separately

```
loop 1: 
df['A'][df_indexes['x'].values]

lopp 2:
df['B'][df_indexes['y'].values]
```

and then munge them back together.

How to do this in a one shot numpy way?

Answer (score 1):

Normally don't use an index array like where the x dim is in both columns. very odd to work with. This will be very fast however.

```
In [85]: DataFrame({'A' : df.iloc[df_index['x'].values]['A'].reset_index(drop=True), 
                    'B' : df.iloc[df_index['y'].values]['B'].reset_index(drop=True)})
Out[85]: 
    A   B
0  15  95
1  15  91
2  11  94
3  13  93
4  12  92
5  12  92
6  12  92
7  11  95

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```